# How to read a floating point value correctly from an XML file independently from regional settings?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, regional-settings, txmldocument

I am reading a floating point attribute value from a node in an XML file with `TXMLDocument`:

```
<MyApp_Favorites version="1.0">
```

...with this statement:

```
var
  ThisRootNode: IXMLNode;
  ThisVersion: Single;

// ...

ThisVersion := ThisRootNode.Attributes['version'];
CodeSite.Send('ThisVersion', ThisVersion);
```

However, on my German language system I get this version value:

> ThisVersion = 10,00

...as in my regional settings the comma "," is defined as decimal separator and not the dot "." as in the XML file. But with an English language regional setting - where the dot is most probably defined as decimal separator setting - the result will be correct as "1.0".

So how can I make sure that independently from the regional setting the read VALUE of **1.0** will be always the same? (Reading the version value as string and then convert it to float doesn't seem to be a very elegant method).

Comment: Here we are again at malicious downvoting of my legitimate and well-formulated questions by some specific people without any explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A floating point number isn't a sensible format for a version number, rounding errors and lack of representability being major drawbacks.  Consider using a record with integers to define the version numbers.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, StrUtils, Types;
type    
TVersion = record
  private
    procedure Set_AsString(AVersion : string);
    function Get_AsString: String;
  public
    Major: Integer;
    Minor: Integer;
    property AsString: String read Get_AsString write Set_AsString;
end;    

function TVersion.Get_AsString: String;
begin
  Result := Format('%d.%d', [Major, Minor]);
end;

procedure TVersion.Set_AsString(AVersion: string);
var
  split : TStringDynArray;
begin
  split := SplitString(AVersion, '.');
  Major := StrToInt(split[0]);
  Minor := StrToInt(split[1]);
end;

var
  v1, v2 : TVersion;
  s : string;
begin
  v1.Major := 12;
  v1.Minor := 34;
  WriteLn(v1.AsString);

  s := v1.AsString;
  v2.AsString := s;

  WriteLn(v2.AsString);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks @J..., but this is only the version of the XML file format and thus doesn't be so complicated.

Comment: Not in the sense of difficult. But your solution is very elegant and complete. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use the string representation and do the conversion yourself using `TFormatSettings.Invariant`:

```
ThisVersion := StrToFloat(ThisRootNode.Attributes['version'], TFormatSettings.Invariant);
```

Answer (score 2):

This value should not be treated as a floating point value. You open yourself up to issues with representation of binary floating point types. Far better is to read the string and parse out major and minor parts, converting them to integer with `StrToInt`. Split the string itself using `Pos` to find the location of the period separator, or indeed using any `Split` function.

On the other hand, it's not even clear that you need this value in any format other than a string. So why bother to do anything beyond reading it as a string?

As for the actual question you asked, should you ever wish to do that use the overload of [`StrToFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToFloat) that accepts a `TFormatSettings` parameter. And pass in format settings that set the decimal separator as `'.'`.

Comment: Well, maybe I could need in the future to make an arithmetical comparison of two or more version values.

Comment: Don't view this as a real value. It's not. It's two integers, major and minor version.

Comment: @user1580348 You can do that with a record using [Operator Overloading](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)#Declaring_Operator_Overloads)

Comment: Enhanced record for a trivial task like this seems over the top.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I suppose, but it depends on how often it gets used.  Adding an operator is also trivial and then you never need to worry about this or similar problems again.